# Given a dictionary of word and frequency pairs, how to proceed with text mining in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining

I already have word frequencies and categories like this:

```
y = ['animals', 'restaurants', 'sports']
x = [{'cat':1, 'dog':2}, {'food':4, 'drink':2}, {'baseball':4, 'basketball':5}]
```

How should I proceed with building the pipeline per the tutorial as follows:

```
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
...                      ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
...                      ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
... ])

>>> text_clf = text_clf.fit(twenty_train.data, twenty_train.target)
```

CountVectorizer is expecting a string... I guess I could create a string from the dictionary and repeat each word the number of times it occurs?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have word frequencies then use a [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

pipeline = Pipeline([('dvect', DictVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())])
model = pipeline.fit(x, y)
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> model.predict([{'cat':1}])[0]
'animals'
```